# sending mail error python

Tags: python

i get the following error when trying a script thaat sends mail

```
    import urllib.request
    import re
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    page=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.crummy.com/")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
    v=soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('http://www.crummy.com/2012/07/24/0'))
    for link in v:

      w=link.get('href')


    server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
    server.starttls()
    server.login( 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx' )
    server.sendmail( 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', "bonus question is up" )
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Python32\bonus", line 14,
>   in   server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )  File
>   "C:\Python32\lib\smtplib.py", line 259, in **init**   File
>   "C:\Python32\lib\smtplib.py", line 319, in connect
>       self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)   File "C:\Python32 \lib\smtplib.py", line 294, in _get_socket
>       return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)   File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 386, in create_connection
>       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed plse advice on the
>   best way to go round it

Answer (score 5):

The `getaddrinfo` function has this purpose:

> The getaddrinfo function provides protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address.

If it fails it means that it cannot translate your given hostname to it's respective address. It's essentially doing a DNS query.

Your error number returned "11004" by `getaddrinfo` has this message associated with it:

> Valid name, no data record of requested type. The requested name is
>   valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct
>   associated data being resolved for. The usual example for this is a
>   host name-to-address translation attempt (using gethostbyname or
>   WSAAsyncGetHostByName) which uses the DNS (Domain Name Server). An MX
>   record is returned but no A record—indicating the host itself exists,
>   but is not directly reachable.

It seems the name you're looking up has no correct data associated with it.

Are you sure your URL's are correct?

Links:

`getaddrinfo`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

WinSock Error Codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx